Flutter reproduce TextField OutlineInputBorder style for other widget
I want the color picker to have exactly the same style than le TextField : label + border color. How can I do that?


see InputDecorator

Can you give more information @pskink? Maybe some code to share?

InputDecorator(decoration: ..., child: ...)

Finally this worked, thank you @psink
    InputDecorator(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'Color',
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
    ),
    child: ColorPicker(...),
  )

